# On convergence of expectations

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, expected-value

Suppose I have a sequence of probability measures $P^n$ which converges weakly to a probability measure $P$. Suppose also I have a sequence of bounded functions $f_n$ converging to a function $f$.

Is there any theorem which allows to conclude that
$$\mathbb E_{P^n}(f_n)\to\mathbb E_P(f)?$$

Comment: This [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07931) might be useful.

Comment: In what sense do the functions converge?